# How query a command in SQLite with error report to MessageBox

Tags: c#, sqlite

How do it? I spent 20 minutes searching it, but finded how to query a command, but is buggly. I use *System.Data.SQLite*

```
try 
{ 

    SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(label2.Text); 
    cnn.Open();//Error is here! 
    SQLiteCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand(); 
    cmd.CommandText = textBox1.Text; 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); MessageBox.Show("Query is good!"); 
    cnn.Close();

} 
catch (SQLiteException ee) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
}
```

Comment: Try Catch Statement, show some code please.

Comment: try
            {
                SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(label2.Text);
                cnn.Open();//Error is here!
                SQLiteCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = textBox1.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Query is good!");
                cnn.Close();
            }
catch (SQLiteException ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
            }

Comment: ERROR: Invalid ConnectionString format for part "D:\myserver\resources\default\scriptfiles\server.db", no equal sign found
but, i dont know, if try function :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot the data source before your path

```
@"data source=C:\mydb.db"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the prefix @ character to rid issues of special characters, or you can just add escape caharacters :-

```
@"D:\myserver\resources\default\scriptfiles\server.db"



"D:\\myserver\\resources\\default\\scriptfiles\\server.db"
```

Comment: But fixed! I must add before a url this: "URI=File:"